# Cannot enable camera

Tags: raspbian, pi-3b+, camera, raspivid

I've been trying to enable the raspberry pi camera on my new pi 3B with no success.

I've tried updating.
I tried raspi-config on the commandline, enabled the camera and rebooted.
These did not work.

When I open the gui configurations window in:
Preferences > Raspberry Pi Configuration > Interfaces.
The camera option is NOT available.

I've also verified that the camera works, by checking on an older pi3

Output of "cat /etc/os-release":

PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="11"
VERSION="11 (bullseye)"
VERSION_CODENAME=bullseye
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"

Can someone assist.

Comment: Which OS are you using? The very latest Raspberry Pi OS Bullseye has camera issues.

Comment: I am using raspberry pi OS 32 bit. Loaded using raspberrypi imager V1.6.2.

Comment: Does 'cat /etc/os-release' return buster or bullseye? Edit your question with this info.

Comment: PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)" 
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="11"
VERSION="11 (bullseye)"
VERSION_CODENAME=bullseye
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"

Comment: You are using bullseye, edit your question. You may find it easiest to go back to buster. https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=323390

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I've seen the discussion in your last comment. Unfortunately I could not get anything working with it. Where can I get the older OS versions, "Buster" as you suggested. I could not find the options in the Imager app.

Comment: I found the download url. Thanks for all the help.